# Can you stop full website searching on a Google Site?

Tags: google-sites

I'm trying to make a google site but don't want people to be able to search the pages of the website, I was wondering if there was any way of turning this off? I and another person tried for awhile it fix this but wasn't able to get anywhere.

Here is a test site I quickly made to show the problem:
main site - https://sites.google.com/view/testsite78/home

search problem - https://sites.google.com/search/testsite78?query=*

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Found in this [thread](https://support.google.com/sites/thread/4710361/can-t-remove-search-function-on-the-new-google-sites) and based on a Product Expert, there is no way to hide the search feature. You can hide pages from navigation but people can still get to it with a link. You can send feedback to the Google Sites developers to suggest this feature.

To send feedback, click the 3-dot icon next to the publish button while in edit mode and select "Report a problem". You can request the feature and that way Google will keep track of the request.